Run an API batch file to the last full week (Friday) on a weekly basis
I've got an API batch file that spits out individual files but I'm having to set the dates each week. Is there a way to run it from a specific start date eg 01-01-2024 up to the full Friday?
Tried a few examples but I'm not a coder and would really use the help
Example Below:
@echo off
cd C:\scripts
python api_report.py

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set the start date (1 January of the current year)
REM set start_year=%date:~10,4%
REM set start_date=%start_year%-08-11

REM Set the end date (10 August of the current year)
REM set end_date=%start_year%-08-16

REM Set the start date (YYYY-MM-DD)
set start_date=2024-10-12

REM Set the end date (YYYY-MM-DD)
set end_date=2024-10-18

REM Loop through each day from the start date to the end date
for /L %%A in (0,1,365) do (
    REM Get the current date in the loop
    set "current_date=!start_date!"
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%B in ("!current_date!") do (
        set year=%%B
        set month=%%C
        set day=%%D
        
        REM Format the output filename as "YYYY-MM-DD Rates"
        set "output_file=%%B-%%C-%%D Rates.txt"
        
        REM Construct the URL by replacing YYYY, MM, DD with the actual year, month, and day
        REM original: set "EXAMPLE"
        set "EXAMPLE"

        rem set "formatted_url=https://example.com/rates/%%B-%%C-%%D"
        
        REM Display the formatted URL
        echo Formatted URL: !formatted_url!
        
        REM Use curl to download the content and save it to the output file
        curl --ssl-no-revoke "!formatted_url!" -o "!output_file!"

        REM Increment the current date
        for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%E in ('powershell "(Get-Date -Date '!current_date!').AddDays(1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"') do set start_date=%%E

        REM Check if the current date is beyond the end date
        if !start_date! gtr %end_date% (
            goto endloop
        )
    )
)

:endloop
echo Done.
pause


PowerShell is not needed because you already clearly have python available to you. Python can already convert date strings to date objects, work between a range of dates, and calculate the date of last Friday. I gave you links for at least two duplicates covering some of those yesterday in Staging Ground. You should have read them and tried them by now!

Here's my approach, without using powersmell:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "restart_file=u:\restart_file.txt"

:: Produce results for the start date specified (%1) and next 6 days
:: If %1 is missing, read start date from file
:: If %2 is anything (or %1='skip', do not update file)

SET "skipupdate=%~2"
SET "start_date=%~1"
IF /i "%start_date%"=="skip" SET "skipupdate=Y"&SET "start_date="
IF NOT DEFINED start_date FOR /f %%b IN ('type "%restart_file%" 2^>nul') DO SET "start_date=%%b"
IF NOT DEFINED start_date ECHO no START date?&GOTO :eof

SET /a days=7

ECHO starting with %start_date%" for %days%

:nextday

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%g in ("%start_date%") do (
 SET "year=%%g"
 SET "Month=1%%h"
 SET "Day=1%%i"
 set "output_file=%%g-%%h-%%i Rates.txt"
 set "formatted_url=https://example.com/rates/%%g-%%h-%%i"
)

ECHO curl --ssl-no-revoke "%formatted_url%" -o "%output_file%"

:: increment date
:: Note Month and Day are 100+actual
SET /a day+=1
IF %day% == 132 GOTO nextmonth
IF %day% leq 128 GOTO reassembledate
:: Feb 29th?
SET /a leap=year %% 4
IF %month%%day%==102129 IF %leap%==0 (GOTO reassembledate) ELSE (GOTO nextmonth)
IF %month%%day%==102130 GOTO nextmonth
FOR %%b IN (04 06 09 11) DO IF "%month%%day%"=="1%%b131" GOTO nextmonth
::
:reassembledate
SET "start_date=%year%-%month:~-2%-%day:~-2%"
SET /a days-=1
IF %days% neq 0 GOTO nextday
:: Done #days
IF NOT DEFINED skipupdate ECHO %start_date%>"%restart_file%"

ECHO done

GOTO :eof

:: 1st of new month

:nextmonth
SET /a day=101
SET /a month+=1
IF %month%==113 (SET /a year+=1&SET /a month=101)
GOTO reassembledate

Soo... the first part is simply determining which parameters are provided.
If no date parameter is provided, try to read from a file
Split the date according to original syntax. Note that the settings for month and day include a leading 1, so September would be 109 for instance. This is to permit easier calculations as 09 would be interpreted as an octal number (it starts 0) and 09 is invalid-octal.
So build output_file and formatted_url from the parts
Then echo the curl line (for verification - remove the echo keyword to invoke curl)
Bump the date, format it appropriately (see set /? or many examples on SO for docco) and decrement the days count.
If any left, try again with the new start_date
Else record the start of the next week in the file if permitted.
So, running the code with no parameters each week via a scheduled task on Saturday would produce results for the prior Saturday..Friday.
